# CSS position relative button

Tags: css

I have a problem about layout , you can see the website menu hide by the button

[http://jsfiddle.net/marco90628308/4Vz99/]

i have set the button to position:relative ,if i don't set to position relative that will all right,why? Thanks

Comment: check css z-index of your menu, buttons and buttons container

Comment: Don't link it to active site. Bcoz the question will not help any other people if it's fixed. You'll better make jsfiddle, or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try positioning and set `z-index` for the `#header`

It worked on fiddle that you gave...

[image]

Comment: I have try to set #header to position:absolute and z-index:1,but is same,i have upload to fiddle,Thanks